# Converting 1D byte Array to 1D Integer Array

Tags: java

I want to convert 1-D Byte Array of pixels of an Image to 1-D integer Array.
I have the following code as below:

```
Byte[] pixels = (Byte[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(0, 0, width, height, null);

int[] array = new int[pixels.length];

for (int k = 0; k < pixels.length; k++);{
  array[k] = pixels[k++];
}
```

Whenever I am compiling this code , I am getting the below run time exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Byte;

Comment: Side note: in case `img.getRaster()` is your own code --- consider not returning an array of Byte, but byte. You really want to be careful about the compiler doing boxing/unboxing all over the place; as such things can substantially impact your performance on larger sets of data.

Comment: I tried but again getting the same exception:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Byte;

Comment: @Jägermeister `img.getRaster()` is not custom code but most probably `BufferedImage#getRaster()`.

Comment: img.getRaster()  is a function cming from ImageIo library.

Comment: IIRC `[B` means a `byte[]` array which is something different than a `Byte[]` array. Boxing doesn't work here. Given that message I'd assume you're not showing us the actual code.

Comment: Update: it seems that at least some compilers can convert and unbox, i.e. `array[k] = pixels[k++];` should actually work. The error message indicates that's not the actual code or at least not the line where the error happens. Please post the line mentioned in the exception's stack trace.

Comment: The Actual Code is:  BufferedImage img = null;

  try {
   img = ImageIO.read(new File("location"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }int width = img.getWidth();
  int height = img.getHeight();int k;
  Byte[] pixels = (Byte[]) img.getRaster().getDataElements(0, 0, width, height, null);
  System.out.println(pixels);
  
  int[] array = new int[pixels.length];
  for (k = 0; k < pixels.length; k++);{
   array[k] = (byte) pixels[k++].intValue();
  }

Comment: Don't put such code updates into comments but add them to your question as an edit.

Answer (score 3):

I see 3 issues in your code

1. To convert a `Byte` to the primitive type `int` you need to call `intValue()`
2. You increment twice your local variable `k` such that you will exceed the size of your array
3. You do an invalid cast according to your exception, `getDataElements` returns

> An object reference to an array of type defined by **getTransferType()**
>   with the requested pixel data.

So you should check first `getTransferType()` to know how to cast it properly. But it seems to be an array of the primitive type `byte` instead of an array of the wrapper class `Byte` such that `Byte[] pixels` should be `byte[] pixels`.

So the expected code should be:

```
for (int k = 0; k < pixels.length; k++);{
    array[k] = pixels[k];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pixels is an array of Byte objects. You are trying to assign it to an array of ints. You should have something like this: `array[k] = pixels[k++].intValue();`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Raster#getDataElements()` returns a `byte[]` array (`[B`) in your case ( `img.getRaster()` returns a `WritableRaster` and the raster's type most likely is `DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE`). You, however, try to cast that to a `Byte[]` array (`[Ljava.lang.Byte`) which is something else and since no automatic conversion exists you get the `ClassCastException`.

Change your code to use `byte[]` instead and all should be fine.